# Sapply produces NA when large numbers are used in R

Tags: r, sapply

Here are two examples using sapply, the first example works but the second example produces NA when x is large numbers. Can anyone help?

This works

```
x = 1:10
y = 5:15
sapply(x, function (i) min(abs(x[i]-y)))
```

But this does not work

```
x = 100000:100010
y = 5:15
sapply(x, function (i) min(abs(x[i]-y)))
```

Comment: You presumably want `sapply(x, function (i) min(abs(i-y)))`?

Comment: or `sapply(1:length(x),function(i) min(abs(x[i]-y)))`

Comment: I don't think 'simple typographical error' applies here, unless the asker clarifies: this is more likely a lack of understanding of how `sapply` works, which isn't the same as a typo (where the asker understands how the function works and just types the wrong thing by accident).

Comment: @Joe -  I agree.  It's not a typo

Answer (score 1):

When using `i` as you are using it, you'll need use a sequence in the `X` argument of `sapply`.
It's just like using `i` in a `for` loop

```
> x <- 1:10
> y <- 5:15
> sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) min(abs(x[i] - y)))
# [1] 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
> x <- 100000:100010
> y <- 5:15
> sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) min(abs(x[i] - y)))
# [1] 99985 99986 99987 99988 99989 99990 99991 99992 99993 99994 99995
```

Comment: In case it's unclear, the reason both this and my answer are correct answers is that this generates the values for the indices of x (1 through 10) as the first argument, not the values of `x` themselves, meaning it's a valid set of indices for `x`.  Mine directly iterates over the values of `x` but uses those correctly in the function (not as indices).  I'd be curious to know which is more commonly used; my way seems more consistent with modular programming (functions shouldn't rely on 'global' variables per se) but this is an inline function, so perhaps this is better for performance reasons.

Comment: Between the two, yours is the better method and the method I would definitely use.  I was just pointing out the mistake.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I'm mostly not an [tag:r] programmer so wasn't sure if there was a better way - thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Although, I wouldn't use `i` or `j`, as I usually reserve those for iterations like in my answer.  If the variables are `x` and `y`, I might switch `i` to `a` to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

The argument in the inline function in `sapply` is what each value of the first argument is inserted into, so in your case x[i] is not using i from 1 to 10 or whatever, but i from x[1] to x[end].

```
sapply(x,function(i) min(abs(i-y)))
```

That's what you're trying to do (take each element of `x` and subtract y from).

```
> x = 100000:100010
> y=5:15
> sapply(x,function(i) min(abs(i-y)))
# [1] 99985 99986 99987 99988 99989 99990 99991 99992 99993 99994 99995
```